# Oracle DB Multiple Instances configuration

Tags: database, oracle, instances, sid

I am using Oracle database in my local PC. I have 3 instances database running.
My question is, Do i need to specify different listener for each SID in my machine? 
or I can just have 1 listener on port 1521 for every SID?

If I need to create each Listener for each SID, what is the pros and cons?
Because I see the blog which create each listener for each SID in the same server.
http://www.snoozingdragon.com/information-technology/tips-and-tricks/multiple-listeners-for-multiple-sid-in-oracle-database-6.html

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You do not need to have multiple listeners for several databases. Even if you have different versions of Oracle Database software. Listener from upper version (for ex. 12c) supports connections to 12c, 11g, 10g databases

Multiple listeners are used when we need restrict access from some users, or if one listener is not keeping up with too many connections, etc.

I personally have 4 databases on my laptop, and they all use one listener.